# How to initialize Materialize js file input elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design, materialize

I am appending file input html elements at ajax success response, 
and i am using materialize css.

Here is the url: http://archives.materializecss.com/0.100.2/forms.html

In case of select box element. I am initializing select box  using ex:

```
$('select').material_select();
```

Its working perfect.

But in case of file input it is not working.
How to init file input element using jquery.

```
<div class="file-field input-field">
  <div class="btn">
    <span>File</span>
    <input type="file">
  </div>
  <div class="file-path-wrapper">
    <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Materialize, instead of the the file input field, reset input text that follows it. With jQuery like this :

```
$('.validate').replaceWith('<input class="file-path validate" type="text">');
```